# Repaint JPanel from actionlistener

Tags: java, jpanel, repaint, cardlayout

I know there are multiple threats on how to repaint a JPanel. I've been trying to repaint a JPanel from inside an actionlistener by applying the revalidate() and repaint() methods (as found at stackoverflow). Sadly enough this isn't working. But when i just change the text of a button, it's repainting!

```
public SimulationPanel()
{
      //configure panel.....

      /* ActionListener */
      btnStepsIntoFuture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {               
            //Do something
            /* refresh grid panel */
            worldPanel.createGrid();
            simPanel.revalidate(); //= not working
            simPanel.repaint(); //= not working
            //btnEndSim.setText("End world simulation "); = working
            //btnEndSim.setText("End world simulation"); = working          
        }
      });

     /* Add components to Simulationpanel */
     simPanel.add(buttonsOnTopPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     simPanel.add(worldPanel.getWorldPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
     simPanel.add(stepsIntoFuturePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

**extra info:** the worldpanel is a grid inside the simulationpanel but I guess this doesn't matter because the repaint works by changing the text of the buttons..

**EDIT:**

```
    public void createGrid(){ 
    /* Set constraint on GridBagLayout */
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    /* Create world grid with panels */
    for (int row = 0; row < SettingsPanel.getNrOfRows(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SettingsPanel.getNrOfColumns(); col++) {
            /* Add constraint for correct dimension (row ; column) */
            gbc.gridx = col;
            gbc.gridy = row;

            /* Initialize new cell in world grid */
            CellPanel cellPanel = new CellPanel();

            /* Draw elements of grid */
            drawBackgroundIcons(cellPanel, row, col);
            drawBorders(cellPanel, row, col);

            worldPanel.add(cellPanel, gbc);
        }
    }
    /* Print overview */
    printOverviewOfWorld();
 }


/*  draw background icon of object */
public void drawBackgroundIcons(CellPanel cellPanel, int row, int col)
{
    /*  Set person, zombie weapon icon as background image */
    if(personArray[row][col] != null)
    {
        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/"+personArray[row][col].getName()+".png")).getImage();
        cellPanel.setImg(img);
    }

}
```

I let the objects move 1 step on the grid (right, left, up, diagonal, ...) by changing the position in the twodimensional array.

How can I make it work with the revalidate/repaint methods?

Cheers

Comment: The question is what does `worldPanel.createGrid();` do? You invoke a method on "worldPanel". Do you actually create new components and add the components to the "simPanel"? You can't just create a new reference to the worldPanel variable and expect the components to automatically be added to the simPanel. So basically we can't answer your question because we have no idea what your code really does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the question. The components are added correctly to the simPanel. But when I perform a step into the future I don't add extra components, i just want the background to be changed. thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You may use the method update(Graphics g) like below :

```
jPanel.update(jPanel.getGraphics());
```

worked for me without having to use any Worker or Runnable.

still can't figure out why it repaints the Minimum Size of JFrame , but It works.